# Maven and ibiblio

Tags: maven, jar, repository, pom.xml

I searched a lot in apache documentation and ibiblio.org and I could not find a decent straight answer.

My questions:

1. When I download a jar using maven dependency (setup in pom), how can I be sure that the file does not change on the remote repository? for example, if I'm using log4j version 1.2.3,  downloaded from ibiblio.org (or any other repo for that matter), how can I be sure I'm getting the exact same jar each time?
2. Does maven delete jars from the local repository? let's assume I'm not clearing the repository at all, will it fill up eventually? or does maven have some kind of mechanism to clear old jars?

Answer (score 1):

In Maven conventions a released version like log4j 1.2.3 will never be changed. It will be left in your locale repository until you manually delete it. It can't be changed by anyone except for the admins on maven central, but i suppose they don't do such a stupid thing.

Furthermore the download by default is done from maven central (repo1.maven.org/maven2 instead of ibiblio).

One of the "tricks" in Maven is download an artifact (released) only once...that improved your build performance in contradiction to the SNAPSHOT dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your own repository, and point all your project poms at that. It's easy to configure your poms to use a different (private) repository, but I've never set one up myself. Doesn't seem too hard, other than managing it to keep all the needed artifacts available.